# Black Video Borders - CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

So I have this video embedded into one of my pages. I keep getting these black borders on the top and bottom of it in Internet Explorer. I've tried changing the background, background-color, everything. I get the same issue in IE11 and Edge. Everything works fine in Chrome, firefox, etc.

Photo:
[image]

```html
<video class="video-scroll" poster="fallbackImage" data-src="videoURL"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Video Example :

Note : poster will be add as a background

```
<video width="320" height="240" style="border:2px solid #000;" poster="video-poster1.jpg" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: The question didn't ask about html border, rather about the letterbox.